# How to set enum variable observable?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Please help.I use flutter and GetX.
How to set enum variable observaible? `enum MyEnumType {open,close}; var _myEnumTypeVar = MyEnumType.open.obs;`

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use the `Rx` constructor with Type parameter:

```
class EnumX extends GetxController {
  Rx<MyEnum> myEnum = Rx<MyEnum>(MyEnum.open);
}

enum MyEnum {
  open,
  close
}
```

Example for using enum for @chichi comment/question:

```
    EnumX ex = Get.put(EnumX());

    print('enum: ${ex.myEnum.value}');

    ex.myEnum(MyEnum.close);
    //ex.myEnum.value = MyEnum.close; ← same as this

    print('enum: ${ex.myEnum.value}');
```

Comment: How can I update this enum with?  `EnumX.myEnum(close) ` seems not working

Comment: myEnum.value = MyEnum.close; -> this will notify the Obx observables on the UI